# Loading file with simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, simplexml

I am puzzled why this is not working yet i can echo the test.xml

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo $movies->movie[1]->plot;
?>
```

Comment: If you can print the text.xml, you need to load string, not file.

Comment: why is this wrong $data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/test.xml');

Comment: It's not incorrect. I'll give you a better answer than a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no need to do both, `simplexml_load_file` *and* create a new `SimpleXML` object.**

[`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) already interprets an XML *file* into an object. (Keep in mind, it does not accept an XML string)

```
$movies = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
```

Alternatively, you may directly load an XML *string* into a [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) object.

```
$movies = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('test.xml'));
```

Either of the above approaches can be used to execute the following:

```
echo $movies->movie[0]->plot;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you go to load XML data, there's two ways to do it. You either load the contents of the XML file as a string, then pass that string to Simple XML:

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents('test.xml'); # reads the file and returns the string

$xml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents); # creates a Simple XML object from a string

print_r($xml); # output is a Simple XML object
```

...or, you load the file directly into a Simple XML Object:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml'); # Instantiates a new Simple XML object from the file, without you having to open and pass the string yourself

print_r($xml); # output is a Simple XML object
```

References:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php